# how to add more navigation menu links in navigation bar

Tags: html, templates, navigation, blogger

how to add more navigation links in template? i tried many ways but i could not.

```
<div id='nav-wrapper'>
<div id='nav'>
<b:section class='page' id='page' showaddelement='no'>
  <b:widget id='PageList1' locked='false' title='Pages' type='PageList' version='1'>
    <b:widget-settings>
      <b:widget-setting name='pageListJson'><![CDATA[{'home': {'href': 'https://checkgamezones.blogspot.com/', 'title': 'Home', 'position': 0}}]]></b:widget-setting>
      <b:widget-setting name='homeTitle'>Home</b:widget-setting>
    </b:widget-settings>
    <b:includable id='main'>
<div class='widget-content'>
<ul>
<b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
<b:if cond='data:link.isCurrentPage'>
<li class='selected'><a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a></li>
<b:else/>
<li><a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a></li>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
</ul>
</div>
</b:includable>
  </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please clear me about your query.

If you want more navigation widgets or sections. Just copy the code and Paste where you want to add it.
*** But you need to change section id and widgets id.
And section and widgets only supported in templates not in post. Or you can go to Layout > add a new gadget > add Pages > Add your links and save the widget.

Or.

If you want to add more links in this navigation menu just go to Layout > Select 'Edit' of this pagelist and add new link there.

Comment: I want to add more links like (action, sports, racing) in navigation. there is no option in layout  for navigation. So kindly tell how can i add more navigation links as given.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class='selected'><a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a></li>
```

the element with the a tag is your link if you want to add more do something like this

```
<li class='selected'><a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a></li>
<li class='selected'><a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a></li>
<li class='selected'><a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a></li>
<li class='selected'><a expr:href='data:link.href'><data:link.title/></a></li>
```

Comment: when i add above code then all links show llike this (home home home home) but I want to add links in navigation like (action, racing etc)

Comment: maybe you need to take a course in basic html first.